# Seemingly unmatched BIC and the national bank code on the statement of my account

Tags: iban

The national bank code in my IBAN is 10040000. Acording to various free online services (iban-rechner.de, finanzrechner.org etc) the corresponding BIC must be COBADEBB, but on the statements of my account it's COBADEFF. What might be the reason? Should I not trust those services?
My bank branch is in Berlin.

Answer (score 2):

First one (COBADEBB) is the SWIFT Code for COMMERZBANK AG in BERLIN, while the second is the SWIFT Code of COMMERZBANK AG in FRANKFURT AM MAIN.

For more information check ISO 9362 (https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:9362:ed-4:v1:en)